# PHP array problem

Tags: php, arrays

```
<?php
$d1 = '1';
$d2 = '1';
$d3 = '1';

$date2 = ''.$d1.','.$d2.','.$d3.'';
```

I want to to put these values in an array, but when I assign a variable as `array($date2)` it just gets printed as 'Array'.

What is the problem?

*Updated, this is the code that is printing 'Array':

```
$date2 = array($date);

echo $date2;
```

Comment: Where does it show "Array"? Please show the full code

Comment: You need to use `print_r()` to view the contents of an array.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, you cannot just `echo array('data');`.

To put data into an array such as that, you need to specify it in the following format:

```
$array = array($d1,$d2,$d3); //build array
print_r($array); //show array contents
echo $array[0] //echo first array element
```

You can also add data to an array as follows:

```
// add to array
$array[] = 'item 1';
$array[] = 'item 2';

// add to array
array_push($array,'item 3');
```

Additional reading: [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) & [arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$date2 = array($d1, $d2, $d3);
```

That will create an array with those values.

If you want to view the contents of the array, do this:

```
var_dump($date2);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show what's in an array you can use [var_dump](http://php.net/var_dump) or [print_r](http://php.net/print_r). You can't use `echo` to view an array (unless you do it like Briedis describes).

Answer (score 1):

Putting in the array:

```
$array['key'] = "Value";
```

Printing out:

```
echo "Array: " . $array['key'];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$date2[] = array();
$date2[0] = 10;
$date2[1] = 20;
$date2[2] = 30;
```

Comment: This is misleading. $date2[] = array(); means that the $array[0] will contain an array() (as an element).

Answer (score 0):

```
$date2 = array();
array_push($date2,$d1);
array_push($date2,$d2);
array_push($date2,$d3);// or one in all $date2 = array($var1,$var,$var3);
print_r($date2);
```

for printing array use `print_r`

Comment: how? will you please explain? i want to use it for flash graph <br> this is used to show data in graph $bar->set_values($date2);

Comment: if $bar is an array like `$bar=array();` then you can do `$bar=$date2` and then `print_r($bar);`

Answer (score 0):

you should define `$date2` like this:

```
$date2 = ($d1,$d2,$d3);
```

the way you have it now, `$date2` is just a string of concatenated values

Answer (score 0):

As you wrote using

```
  print_r(array($date2));
```

will output `Array ( [0] => 1,1,1 )`

If you want add the three values separatly you should write this:

`$date2 = array($d1, $d2, $d3);`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code it will give you the expected output. There are three way print_r() , var_dump() and the ever green foreach(). you can use any of them.

```
<?php
$d1 = '1';
$d2 = '1';
$d3 = '1';

$date = ''.$d1.','.$d2.','.$d3.'';
$date2 = array($date);

echo "with print_r:";
print_r($date2);
echo "<hr/>";
echo "with var_dump:";
var_dump($date2);
echo "<hr/>";

echo "with foreach:<br/>";
foreach($date2 as $v)
    echo "$v<br/>";
?>
```